# How would I return a string without the first 2 characters?

Tags: java, string

How would I return a string without the first 2 characters?

But I have to keep the first character if the character is the letter a and the second character if its the letter b.

**Example:**

> **Google** to **ogle**
>   **Albert** to **Abert**
>   **Obsidian** to **bsidian**
>   **absolute** to **absolute**

Comment: What have you tried so far? We're not going to write the code for you.

Comment: Request you to please add some sample code that you have tried out, Then will add the solution

Answer (score 0):

Simple substring and if else statements for the characters. 
For example:

```
String name = "Google";

if (Character.toLowerCase(name.charAt(1)) != 'b') {
    name = name.charAt(0) + ((name.length() > 2) ? name.substring(2, name.length()) : "");
}
if (Character.toLowerCase(name.charAt(0)) != 'a') {
    name = name.substring(1, name.length());
}

System.out.println(name);
```

Comment: Will throw `StringIndexOutOfBoundException` if the length of given string is less than 2.

Comment: Okay, should be fixed now. I just added a ternary operator to check if the length of the string is more than 2, if so then it will substring from 2, if not then it will just be the first character and then carry on with the process.